# Nginx, virtualenv, Django and PIL error

Tags: nginx, python-imaging-library, virtualenv, ubuntu-10.04, pip

I have a working Django setup with DUNG. Django, Unix(ubuntu lucid), Nginx and Gunicorn.

This works nice, I then installed PIL inside my Virtualenv with **pip install pil**.

that installed fine, but when uploading images i got the "Image is corrupt etc messag"

Then I removed PIP from virtualenv and installed **aptitude install libjpeg libjpeg-dev**

Now this is where I am, I now get a server error when trying to uplaod with this error:

**ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed**

This is driving me insane. Im not a expert on any of this.

**EDIT**

i tried importing _imaging from my virtualenv python manage.py shell and got this:

**libjpeg.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Getting closer...

Answer (score 0):

Don't install PIL with `pip`. It requires a ton of development packages of the different image format to be useful. Instead, install PIL from your OS:

```
aptitude install python-imaging
```

And then link PIL into your virtualenv.